# ExtJS 4 Combobox with Sub-Combobox

Tags: extjs, combobox

Is it possible to create a combobox that contains a value of another combobox?

Example:

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/comboboxjrv2sc4zi6.png

When i Mouseover on "Value 1" than should be opend another combobox.

Comment: This looks like a menu? I think you can change value of second combobox with onChange event on the first combobox.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Vlad said,
there are 2 options:

1. create a **menu** within menu:

`{
                text: 'Option 1',
                menu: {        // submenu
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Option 1 - 1'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Option 1 - 2'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Option 1 - 3'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Option 1 - 4'
                        }
                    ]
                }
           }`

1. create a **combobox** that on `mouseover` filter another combo (you can even show the combo on `mouseover`

Answer (score 0):

I would go for menu. Menu can be attached to a button, then it would behave almost like  combo. See [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/menu/menus.html) - first button on the left.